# No Receiving Email From Apex Class

Tags: apex

I have been working in a Visualforce page (form), where when user fills up the form, a record is inserted in Salesforce (this works properly), and then is redirected to a "Thank you" page (this also work fine), but I also want to receive an email with the fields and values of each record that is inserted in Saleforce.

In my `emailSent` method I have a try-catch block that when I run it in the Anonymous window, the email is sent succesfully but in this case the fields only have 'null' values, so, that's fine. But when I create the record from the Visualforce page (Site.com) the record is properly created and I am redirected to the thank you page fine as well, but no email!

I have been trying so many things, even email relays but nothing yet, the only thing that I have not been able to configure is DKIM Keys. I hope that is not necessary, but I think that probably I will need to do that since is a State goverment org.

Here is my apex class code (sorry I know that is very messy the code but I will fix it):

```
public without sharing class JobOrder_Controller {
    
    //private final Job_Order__c jOrder;
    public Job_Order__c jOrder { get; set;}

    
    public JobOrder_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController stdCon){
        this.jOrder = (Job_Order__c)stdCon.getRecord();
    }
    
    //Inserts record after user clicks on Submit and is redirected to a Thank You page
    public ApexPages.PageReference save(){
        insert jOrder;
        emailSent();
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/ThankYouPage');
        pr.setRedirect(false);
        return pr;
    }
    
    //Method to send email with the record's body (fields information)
    public void emailSent(){
        try{
        Job_Order__c[] jOrder = new Job_Order__c[]{};    
        Job_Order__c orderForm = new Job_Order__c();
            
        Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(2);
            
            //for(Integer i = 0; i < jOrder.size(); i++){
            //if(i >= 0){ 
            List<Job_Order__c> orderList = [SELECT Id, Name, Federal_Employer_Identification_No__c, Date__c, Email__c, Employer_Company_Name__c, Address_Do_not_list_a_P_O_Box__c, City__c, State__c,
                                 Zip_Code__c, County__c,Contact_Person_s_Name__c, Contact_Person_s_Title__c, Phone_No__c, Extension__c, Other__c, Fax_No__c, Company_Website__c,
                                 How_many_people_do_you_employ__c, Which_best_describes_your_company__c, Third_Party_recruiter_staffing_agency__c, Are_you_a_federal_contractor__c,
                                 Company_Description_Type_of_Business__c FROM Job_Order__c WHERE Id =: orderForm.Id LIMIT 1];
            if(!orderList.isEmpty()){
                orderForm = orderList[0];
            }
            //}
    //}
        
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        List<String> sendTo = new List<String>{'I am putting here two emails'};
        //mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
        //mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
        //mail.setWhatId(orderForm.Id);
        //mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
         
        String emailBody;
        emailBody = 'Order Submission \n' + orderForm.Id; 
            if(orderForm.Federal_Employer_Identification_No__c != 0) {emailBody += 'FEI No: ' + orderForm.Federal_Employer_Identification_No__c + '\n';}
            if(orderForm.Date__c != null) {emailBody += 'Date: ' + orderForm.Date__c + '\n';}
            if(orderForm.Email__c != '') {emailBody += 'Email: ' + orderForm.Email__c + '\n';}
            if(orderForm.Employer_Company_Name__c != '') {emailBody += 'Employer/Company Name: ' + orderForm.Employer_Company_Name__c + '\n';}
            if(orderForm.Address_Do_not_list_a_P_O_Box__c != '') {emailBody += 'Address: ' + orderForm.Address_Do_not_list_a_P_O_Box__c + '\n';}
            if(orderForm.City__c != '') {emailBody += 'City: ' + orderForm.City__c + '\n';}
            if(orderForm.State__c != '') {emailBody += 'State: ' + orderForm.State__c + '\n';}
            if(orderForm.Zip_Code__c != 0) {emailBody += 'Zip Code: ' + orderForm.Zip_Code__c + '\n';}
            if(orderForm.County__c != '') {emailBody += 'County: ' + orderForm.County__c + '\n';}
            if(orderForm.Contact_Person_s_Name__c != '') {emailBody += 'Contact\'s Person Name: ' + orderForm.Contact_Person_s_Name__c + '\n';}
            if(orderForm.Contact_Person_s_Title__c != '') {emailBody += 'Contact\'s Person Title: ' + orderForm.Contact_Person_s_Title__c + '\n';}
            if(orderForm.Phone_No__c != '') {emailBody += 'Phone No: ' + orderForm.Phone_No__c + '\n';}
            if(orderForm.Extension__c != null) {emailBody += 'Extension: ' + orderForm.Extension__c + '\n';} 
            if(orderForm.Other__c != '') {emailBody += 'Other: ' + orderForm.Other__c + '\n';}
            if(orderForm.Fax_No__c != '') {emailBody += 'Fax No: ' + orderForm.Fax_No__c + '\n';}
            if(orderForm.Company_Website__c != '') {emailBody += 'Company Website: ' + orderForm.Company_Website__c + '\n';}
            if(orderForm.How_many_people_do_you_employ__c != 0) {emailBody += 'How many people do you employe? ' + orderForm.How_many_people_do_you_employ__c + '\n';}
            if(orderForm.Which_best_describes_your_company__c != '') {emailBody += 'Which best describes your company? ' + orderForm.Which_best_describes_your_company__c + '\n';}
            if(orderForm.Third_Party_recruiter_staffing_agency__c != '') {emailBody += 'Third party/staffing agency? ' + orderForm.Third_Party_recruiter_staffing_agency__c+ '\n';}
            if(orderForm.Are_you_a_federal_contractor__c != '') {emailBody += 'Are you a federal contractor? ' + orderForm.Are_you_a_federal_contractor__c + '\n';}
            if(orderForm.Company_Description_Type_of_Business__c != '') {emailBody += 'Company Description/Type of Business: ' + orderForm.Company_Description_Type_of_Business__c+ '\n';}
            
        System.debug(emailBody);
            
        mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
        //mail.setWhatId(orderForm.Id);
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        
        mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
        //mail.setCcAddresses(ccAddress);
        
        //email where the replies will be sent
        mail.setReplyTo('myEmail');
        
        //Name that will be displayed in the email
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Job Order');
        
        // Specify the subject line for your email address.
        mail.setSubject('New Job Order Created!');

        // Specify the text content of the email.   
        mail.setPlainTextBody(emailBody);
        mail.setHtmlBody(emailBody);
            
               
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
             
       }catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Email sending failed with error: ' + e.getMessage());
       }
        
    }
}
```

And here is my VF Page Code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Job_Order__c" extensions="JobOrder_Controller" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="true" docType="html-5.0" applyHtmlTag="true" cache="true">
    <!-- Page Header -->
    <style>
        #ct
        {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: large;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #header
        {
            font-size: large;
            text-align: center;
            font: bold:
        }
        #italic
        {
            font-style: italic;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- Title and Subtitle -->
    <apex:form id="JobOrder">
        <head align="center">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <div id="ct">
            <apex:sectionHeader title="State Goverment" id="ct"/>
            <apex:sectionHeader subtitle="Division of Employment" />
        </div>
        </head>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <!-- Instructions -->
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Please be as detailed as possible.</h1> 
            <h1 id="italic">(Required fileds are highlighted in red/marked with an asterisk)</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- Fields -->
        <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Information">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.Federal_Employer_Identification_No__c}" required="true" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.Date__c}" required="true"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.Email__c}" required="true" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.Employer_Company_Name__c}" required="true" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.Address_Do_not_list_a_P_O_Box__c}" required="true" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.City__c}" required="true" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.State__c}" required="true" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.Zip_Code__c}" required="true" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.County__c}" required="true" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.Contact_Person_s_Name__c}" required="true" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.Contact_Person_s_Title__c}" required="true" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.Phone_No__c}" required="true" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.Extension__c}" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.Other__c}" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.Fax_No__c}" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.Company_Website__c}" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.How_many_people_do_you_employ__c}" required="true" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.Which_best_describes_your_company__c}" required="true" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.Third_Party_recruiter_staffing_agency__c}" required="true" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.Are_you_a_federal_contractor__c}" required="true" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Order__c.Company_Description_Type_of_Business__c}" required="true" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <!-- Button Section -->
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Submit Order" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

All of this is also done in a sandbox.

Thank you in advance!

I tried Email relays and nothing yet.

I also have Deliverability set as "All Email" and Test Deliverability also send those tests emails